# Implementing a statistical estimator in Python based on Fortran/Julia code

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to implement the O(nlogn) algorithm for calculating Sn (a statistical estimator of scale) as described in "Time-Efficient Algorithms for Two Highly Robust Estimators of Scale", Christophe Croux and Peter J. Rousseeuw.
The paper provides Fortran code, and I also found [this](https://github.com/mrxiaohe/RobustStats.jl/blob/master/src/dispersion_estimators.jl) Julia implementation (`function scaleS!`) and tried to convert it to Python, but my code doesn't work. I think it's because I keep messing up the indexing - both Fortran and Julia start indexing arrays at 1 and Python starts at 0. So here's the Python code:

```
def sn(x):
    N = len(x)

    x.sort()
    a2 = [0] * N
    a2[0] = x[round(N / 2)] - x[0]

    for i in range(1, round((N + 1) / 2) - 1):
        nA = i - 1
        nB = N - i
        diff = nB - nA
        leftA = leftB = 1
        rightA = rightB = nB
        Amin = round(diff / 2) + 1
        Amax = round(diff / 2) + nA
        while leftA < rightA:
            length = rightA - leftA + 1
            even = 1 - (length % 2)
            half = round((length - 1) / 2)
            tryA = leftA + half
            tryB = leftB + half
            if tryA < Amin:
                rightB = tryB
                leftA = tryA + even
            elif tryA > Amax:
                rightA = tryA
                leftB = tryB + even
            else:
                medA = x[i] - x[i - tryA + Amin - 1]
                medB = x[tryB + i] - x[i]
                if medA >= medB:
                    rightA = tryA
                    leftB = tryB + even
                else:
                    rightB = tryB
                    leftA = tryA + even
        if leftA > Amax:
            a2[i] = x[leftB + i] - x[i]
        else:
            medA = x[i] - x[i - leftA + Amin - 1]
            medB = x[leftB + i] - x[i]
            a2[i] = min(medA, medB)

    for i in range(round((N + 1) / 2), N - 2):
        nA = N - i
        nB = i - 1
        diff = nB - nA
        leftA = leftB = 1
        rightA = rightB = nB
        Amin = round(diff / 2) + 1
        Amax = round(diff / 2) + nA
        while leftA < rightA:
            length = rightA - leftA + 1
            even = 1 - (length % 2)
            half = round((length - 1) / 2)
            tryA = leftA + half
            tryB = leftB + half
            if tryA < Amin:
                rightB = tryB
                leftA = tryA + even
            elif tryA > Amax:
                rightA = tryA
                leftB = tryB + even
            else:
                medA = x[i + tryA - Amin + 1] - x[i]
                medB = x[i] - x[i - tryB]
                if medA >= medB:
                    rightA = tryA
                    leftB = tryB + even
                else:
                    rightB = tryB
                    leftA = tryA + even
        if leftA > Amax:
            a2[i] = x[i] - x[i - leftB]
        else:
            medA = x[i + leftA - Amin + 1] - x[i]
            medB = x[i] - x[i - leftB]
            a2[i] = min(medA, medB)

    a2[N] = x[N] - x[round((N + 1) / 2)]
    lomed = a2[round((len(a2) + 1) / 2)]

    return lomed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working direct translation from the [Julia function](https://github.com/mrxiaohe/RobustStats.jl/blob/master/src/dispersion_estimators.jl). The fastest method that I generally use to convert any Julia code into Python is: comment out all `end`s and put the `:` for all conditionals and loops, subtract `1` from all indices, finally replace equivalent functions.

These are some specific points for your code. Note that I removed the `lomed` function and put `sum` as I'm not familiar with the low median concept in statistics.

- Since Python starts indexing arrays at `0`, you'll need to adjust some of the indices in your code to match that.
- The line `round(N / 2)` needs to be changed to `N // 2` since Julia uses `div` and Python equivalent is `//`.
- In the for loop where `i` goes from `1` to `round((N + 1) / 2) - 1`, you'll need to adjust the indices in the slice `x[i - tryA + Amin - 1]` so that they start at `0` instead of `1`.
- In the second for loop where `i` goes from `round((N + 1) / 2)` to `N - 2`, you'll need to adjust the indices in the slice `x[i + tryA - Amin + 1]` so that they start at `0` instead of `1`.

```
def sn(x):
    N = len(x)

    x = sorted(x)
    a2 = [0 for _ in range(N)]
    a2[0] = x[N//2]-x[0]
    for i in range(2,(N+1)//2+1):
        nA = i-1
        nB = N-i
        diff = nB-nA
        leftA = leftB = 1
        rightA = rightB = nB
        Amin = diff//2+1
        Amax = diff//2+nA

        while leftA < rightA:
            lent = rightA-leftA+1
            even = 1 - lent%2
            half = (lent-1)//2
            tryA = leftA+half
            tryB = leftB+half
            if tryA < Amin:
                rightB = tryB
                leftA = tryA + even
            elif tryA > Amax:
                rightA = tryA
                leftB = tryB+even
            else:
                medA = x[i-1]-x[i-tryA+Amin-2]
                medB = x[tryB+i-1] - x[i-1]
                if medA >= medB:
                    rightA = tryA
                    leftB = tryB+even
                else:
                    rightB = tryB
                    leftA = tryA+even
                # end
            # end
        # end
        if leftA > Amax:
            a2[i-1] = x[leftB+i-1]-x[i-1]
        else:
            medA = x[i-1]-x[i-leftA+Amin-2]
            medB = x[leftB+i-1]-x[i-1]
            a2[i-1] = min(medA,medB)
        #end
    #end

    for i in range((N+1)//2+1, N):
        nA = N-i
        nB = i-1
        diff = nB-nA
        leftA = leftB = 1
        rightA = rightB = nB
        Amin = diff//2+1
        Amax = diff//2+nA
        while leftA < rightA:
            lent = rightA-leftA+1
            even = 1-lent%2
            half = (lent-1)//2
            tryA = leftA+half
            tryB = leftB+half
            if tryA < Amin:
                rightB = tryB
                leftA = tryA + even
            elif tryA > Amax:
                rightA = tryA
                leftB = tryB+even
            else:
                medA = x[i+tryA-Amin]-x[i-1]
                medB = x[i-1]-x[i-tryB-1]
                if medA >= medB:
                    rightA = tryA
                    leftB = tryB+even
                else:
                    rightB = tryB
                    leftA = tryA+even
                # end
            # end
        # end
        if leftA > Amax:
            a2[i-1] = x[i-1]-x[i-leftB-1]
        else:
            medA = x[i+leftA-Amin]-x[i-1]
            medB = x[i-1]-x[i-leftB-1]
            a2[i-1] = min(medA,medB)
        # end
    # end # 20

    a2[N-1] = x[N-1]-x[(N+1)//2-1]

    # Normalization
    cn = 1.0
    if N < 10:
        cn = [0, .743, 1.851, .954, 1.351, .993, 1.198, 1.005, 1.131][N-1]
    elif N%2 == 1:
        cn = N/(N-0.9)
    # end
    return cn * 1.1926 * sum(a2)
```